# Phase correlation of periodic images (in log-polar coordinates) nulls out

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pattern-matching, computer-vision, fft

I'm trying to perform rotation-invariant pattern-matching by switching to log-polar coordinates (in this case rotation translates to linear shift) and calculating phase correlation (phaseCorrelateRes function in OpenCV).

But the strange thing happens: peak of phase correlation descreases rapidly from 1 to 0 while the rotation angle increases from 0 to 180 degrees. I suppose this happens because the log-polar image is periodic, so the part that is shifted beyond the border appears from the opposite border and affects the phase correlation, which is strange to me because the phase should not change in this case.

I don't quite understand the mathematics behind this and what should I do to prevent this behaviour (so that correlation would be 1 in all positions, as it happens with non-periodic images)?